# issue with loop not reaching the end of a file - Java

Tags: java, loops, file-handling

I'm working on a Java assignment for school. The assignment is to deal with 2 files reading the first, using the second to make adjustments on the first, and finally, outputing into a new file.

```
    Scanner inputRecords = new Scanner(new File("Records.txt"));
    Scanner inputTransactions = new Scanner(new File("Transactions.txt"));
    BufferedWriter outputFile = (new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("NewRecords.txt", true)));
    char code; // transaction code
    String lineTran = "";
    String lineRecord = "";
    String midS = "";
    String tidS = "";
    int tid = 0,  mid= 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
    {
        lineTran = inputTransactions.nextLine();                
        code = lineTran.charAt(0);
        System.out.println(code);
        tidS = lineTran.substring(2,11);            
        tid = Integer.parseInt(tidS);
        lineRecord = inputRecords.nextLine();
        midS = lineRecord.substring(0,9);
        mid = Integer.parseInt(midS);
        if (mid < tid) // add a new record lineTran.substring(2,lineTran.length()
        {
            outputFile.write(lineRecord);
            outputFile.newLine();
            lineRecord = inputRecords.nextLine();
        }
        else if (mid == tid )
        {
            if (code == 'C') //change record
            {
                outputFile.write(lineTran.substring(2,lineTran.length()));
                outputFile.newLine();
                lineTran = inputTransactions.nextLine();
            }
            else if (code == 'D') //delete record
            {
                lineTran = inputTransactions.nextLine();
                lineRecord = inputRecords.nextLine();
            }
            else // add error
            {
                System.out.println(lineRecord + " Already Exists...add error");
                lineTran = inputTransactions.nextLine();
            }
        }
        else
        {
                if (code == 'A') // add record
                {
                    outputFile.write(lineTran.substring(2,lineTran.length()));
                    outputFile.newLine();
                    lineTran = inputTransactions.nextLine();
                }
                else if (code == 'C') // change error
                {
                    System.out.println(lineRecord + " Record already exist...Change Error");
                    lineTran = inputTransactions.nextLine();
                }
                else // delete error 
                {
                    System.out.println(lineRecord + " Record does not exist...delete error");
                    lineTran = inputTransactions.nextLine();
                }
        }
```

Note that: 
Records.txt has 10 lines of information (example: ######### lastname firstname occupation)
Transactions.txt has 6 lines of information (example: 'A,D,or C' ######### lastname firstname occupation)

The issue I'm having is no matter the type of loop i run i reach one of 2 deadends. 
1) in the case of the for loop above

D
A
C
A
C
386326383 Slim Kan personalTrainer No changes were found...Change Error

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at fileHandling.main(fileHandling.java:26)
is the outcome and nothing writen to file.

2) If I run for loop through x<5 program runs fine and, however, skips the last transaction.

I tried "do while" and "while" loops but only got similar results. any suggestions?

Comment: What is unclear about *"StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0"*? You have empty lines in your file and your code can't handle that.

Comment: no, I made sure that the file is clean and set up correctly and I'm sure there is an extra line that the loop isn't reaching in both cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the `if` condition you have assign `lineTran = inputTransactions.nextLine();` then on the top of `for` loop you assign it again. Means that you are dismiss 1 line every loop. So that, in transaction file you have 6 lines, then you loop will run more loop than the number of line in the file because of you have read `.nextLine()` more than the number of lines.

Comment: the reason why I have the nextLine(); in both spots is because I need part of the first string to check the loop. that being said I will try to open the file and get the first integer I need separately and see if that works.

Comment: I know that you need the `lineTran` for checking in `if` statement, but why you have to change the value of `lineTran` to `nextLine()` in the end of the condition (**you have not use it**) then go back to top you continue change it again. This assignment is harmful, it make you dismiss 1 line.

Comment: I see what you are saying right now. because I have it at the start of loop and in ever check condition I'm skipping lines before using them. I will test moving the initial 'nextLine()' outside the loop.

Comment: Making above adjustments fixed the issue. thank you for your help!